# uploadProgress not being triggered rn-fetch-blob

Tags: react-native, rn-fetch-blob

Working on a react-native app, I'm having the following issue in both platforms (iOS and Android)

Environment:

```
"react-native": "^0.61.1",
"rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
```

I'm doing a multipart request to upload a video to the server. Given this request takes time I would like to show the progress to the user.

According to the library documentation, there is a `uploadProgress` callback: https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob#uploaddownload-progress but is not working on my side.

Here is my code:

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch(
    'POST',
    `${REACT_APP_API_DOMAIN}/upload/video`,
    {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      timestamp: `${timestamp}`,
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
    [
      {
        name: 'video',
        filename: `video.${file.split('.')[file.split('.').length - 1]}`,
        data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(file),
      },
    ],
  )
    .then(() => {
      Notifier.showNotification({
        title: 'The videos was successfully saved!',
        description: "We're processing it, your profile will be updated soon!",
        Component: NotifierComponents.Alert,
      });
      setStatus(statusEnum.PROCESSING);
      completeCallback();
    })
    .uploadProgress((written, total) => {
      console.log('uploaded', written / total);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      Notifier.showNotification({
        title: 'There was an error uploading the video',
        description: err.toString(),
        Component: NotifierComponents.Alert,
        componentProps: {
          alertType: 'error',
        },
      });
      setStatus(statusEnum.FAILED);
      completeCallback();
    });
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I think you should put the `uploadProgress` before the `then` part, so it would be:

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch(...).uploadProgress(...).then(...).catch(...)
```

Edit:

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch(
            'POST',
            video.uploadUrl,
            {
              'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
            [
              {
                name: 'file',
                filename: video.fileName,
                data: RNFetchBlob.wrap(decodeURIComponent(video.uri.replace('file://', ''))),
              },
            ],
          )
```

Comment: I’ve done this put it is still not being triggered. Any idea if this only works with servers/apis that support updating upload progress?

Comment: Sorry but no, I have no idea. I did it like this and it finally worked. I was uploading videos to JWPlayer.

 I'm even using the same version for rn-fetch-blob, I checked: 

"rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"

I do have a higher react native version: 

"react-native": "0.71.8"

Comment: have you by any chance tried uploading to AWS S3? I can't figure out if they just don't support upload progress, or if I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: also, do you happen to be using the multipart upload method described here? https://docs.jwplayer.com/platform/reference/vdh-v2-upload-content#multipart-resumable-upload

Comment: well apparently in the comments I cant add code so I will edit my original post to show you what I did.
And no, I never uploaded to AWS, just JWPlayer, and the backend gave me the URL I needed from JWPlayer so Im not sure about how that part worked